# Mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given

Tags: php, base-de-datos, mysqli, mysql-workbench

estoy intentando mostrar en mi navegador unos datos cogidos de la base de datos y al ejecutarlo me muestra el siguiente error:

**mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given**

Agradecería algo de ayuda.

**Codigo:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento sin título</title>
</head>
<body>

<table border='1px'>
    <tr>
    <td class='fila'>id</td>
    <td class='fila'>Nombre</td>
    <td class='fila'>Apellido</td>
    </tr>
<?php


$host="localhost";
$usuario="php";
$password="prueba";
$basedatos="clientes";

$connection = mysqli_connect($host,$usuario,$password);

function showerror( )   {
    die("Se ha producido el siguiente error: " . mysqli_error($connection));
}
    // Seleccionar la base de datos
if (!(@ mysqli_select_db($basedatos, $connection)))
showerror( );

$SQL=" SELECT id_cliente,nombre,apellido FROM clientes.datos where 
fecha_creacion between '2018-06-15' and '2018-06-01' ";

    if (!($result1 = @ mysqli_query ( $SQL, $connection)))
    showerror( );

while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_row($result1)) {



    print("<tr>");
    print("<td class='fila'>".$row1[0]."</td>");
    print("<td class='fila'>".$row1[1]."</td>");
    print("<td class='fila'>".$row1[2]."</td>");
    print("</tr>");


}


?>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probablemente sea por tu string de conexión. Prueba colocando:

```
$connection = mysqli_connect($host,$usuario,$password, $basedatos);


if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Falló la conexión: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

function showerror( )   {
    die("Se ha producido el siguiente error: " . mysqli_error($connection));
}
```

Al incluir la bd en tu string de conexión ya no es necesario este segmento de código:

```
// Seleccionar la base de datos
if (!(@ mysqli_select_db($basedatos, $connection)))
showerror( );
```

Al final tu código depurado sería el siguiente:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento sin título</title>
</head>
<body>

<table border='1px'>
    <tr>
    <td class='fila'>id</td>
    <td class='fila'>Nombre</td>
    <td class='fila'>Apellido</td>
    </tr>
<?php


$host="localhost";
$usuario="php";
$password="prueba";
$basedatos="clientes";

$connection = mysqli_connect($host,$usuario,$password, $basedatos);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Falló la conexión: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}


function showerror( )   {
    die("Se ha producido el siguiente error: " . mysqli_error($connection));
}


$SQL=" SELECT id_cliente,nombre,apellido FROM clientes.datos where 
fecha_creacion between '2018-06-15' and '2018-06-01' ";

    if ($result1 = mysqli_query($connection, $SQL))
    {

        while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_row($result1)) {

            print("<tr>");
            print("<td class='fila'>".$row1[0]."</td>");
            print("<td class='fila'>".$row1[1]."</td>");
            print("<td class='fila'>".$row1[2]."</td>");
            print("</tr>");

        }
    }

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Para más información puedes revisar [mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php)

Espero sea de ayuda, un saludo!

Comment: Acabo de modificar el codigo y probarlo, soluciona el error comentado, el problema es que ahora me sale el mismo error con: **mysqli_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given** @Huskie

Comment: Estás seguro que tus parametros colocados al string de conexión son exactamente así? el nombre de la bd, el usuario etc?

Comment: Si, acabo de encontrar el error. Tenia mal colocados los parámetros de **mysqli_query** @Huskie Muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: De nada. Me alegra que ya está solucionado. Un saludo!